# Is $f:\mathbb{Q^*} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by $f(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{\max{(a,b)}}{\min{(a,b)}}$ a function?

Tags: functions, relations

Suppose that the relation $f:\mathbb{Q^*} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by 
$$
f \Bigl(\frac{a}{b} \Bigr) = \frac{\max{(a,b)}}{\min{(a,b)}}
$$
is defined. Then is $f$ a function? If so, how would we prove that $f$ is a function?

Comment: What are the possible values of $a$ and $b$? In particular, can $b$ be negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to prove that if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then $$\frac{\max(a,b)}{\min(a,b)}=\frac{\max(c,d)}{\min(c,d)}$$

Then it depends on what $a,b$ are allowed. We know that $a,b\neq 0$, but can they have a common divisor? Can $b$ be negative? Or are we taking some "usual" representation for each rational - for example, $a,b$ relatively prime with $b>0$.

Comment: The problem does not state whether or not $a$ and $b$ are reduced. However, I believe we are assuming the "usual" representation for each rational. How then would we proceed with the proof under this assumption?

Comment: I suspect you are wrong, because these sorts of "is this a function?" questions are trying to test your ability to read definitions. There is a way to make this definition a function, but it is not, as it stands, a function, since $f(\frac{-1}{2})\neq f(\frac{1}{-2})$, and the question doesn't specify which value to choose.